# Errors when attempting to add custom Schema

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api

I am attempting to add a custom schema to users on my Google Domain however I can't get even one to work. I keep getting an error for bad request, I am following all syntax provided.

```
function myFunction() {
 var schema = {
   "kind":"admin#directory#schema",
   "schemaId":"EmployeeInfo",
   "schemaName":"Employee Information",
   "fields":[
     {
       "kind":"admin#directory#schema@fieldspec",
       "fieldId":"EmployeeID",
       "fieldName":"Employee ID",
       "fieldType":"STRING", 
       "readAccessType":"ADMINS_AND_SELF"
     }
    ]
   };
  AdminDirectory.Schemas.insert(schema, "CustomerId");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Create a custom user schema](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas) from Directory API:

To create a custom user schema in your domains, use the following POST request and include the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing). For the request query string properties, see the API Reference.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer or customerId/schemas
```

All create requests require you to submit the information needed to fulfill the request. If you are using client libraries, they convert the data objects from your chosen language into JSON data formatted objects.

**JSON request**

The following JSON shows a sample request to create a custom schema. For the full list of request and response properties, see the API Reference.

```
{
  "schemaName": "employmentData",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "EmployeeNumber",
      "fieldType": "STRING",
      "multiValued": "false"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "JobFamily",
      "fieldType": "STRING",
      "multiValued": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is just copied from the Directory API website, of which I read... Respectfully, this does not answer my question. I have authorized and have run other functions already such has adding and pulling users, I have already authorized the script. I have also used the purposed syntax

Comment: There is also a different error for an unauthorized request, this isn't that.